# VS code Import issue with local module

Tags: python, api, visual-studio-code, module, importerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDcbh.png)

In my virtual environment, I am trying to import "models.py" file into main.py
for that I tried:
""" from . import models, schemas """.
but even though models.py and main.py both file are at same levels I am unable to import it is giving this error:

"""ImportError: cannot import name 'models' from 'app.routers' (unknown location)"""

Comment: your file is in `app` not `app.routers`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is only write `import models, schemas` and access your functions / classes from those files with `models.<classname>` or directly import them using `import <classname> from models`

Answer (score 0):

Vscode takes the workspace as the root directory, so you need to use the following code:

```
from app import models,schemas
```